# Images clicked today

Tags: java, android

I want to extract all the images from the gallery that were clicked today I tried using the managed query I am getting the image data,path and everything else but I can't get Date Added as it returns a string value "date_added"

so is there any way to get that or any way around???

this is the Query I am using

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                                MediaStore.Images.DATE_ADDED };
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED +"= '"+ + "'",
                        null, orderBy);// Couldn't get what to fill here
```